# How to read yaml file in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin, yaml

I have a Kotlin project, I am running a simple `main` function, and I want to start it by reading a YAML file, that is located at the same directory, and saving it into some kind of a data structure, similar to dictionary in Python. How can I do it?

Comment: You could use [some library](https://www.kotlinresources.com/library/kaml/) for it... Or google for another one.

Comment: @dehaar I found this site before. It doesn't explain about files.

Comment: @MorZamir for the Kaml library it should go like this


`val input = File("file.yaml").readLines()
val result = Yaml.default.parse(YourClass.serializer(), input)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reading seems like the same for reading any other file, after that the parsing and mapping depend on you

```
File("/{fullPath}/{ProjectName}/src/reader/example.yaml").forEachLine {
    println(it)
}
```

So I'm using the full path but you can surely optimized that according to your enviroment

Comment: Thanks, do you know how to insert it into a 'dictionary-like' structure in that same call?

Comment: You have to know what you are going to parse first, are you going to parse every attritube/tag/element/node/keyword on the yaml file? Then start creating a file with constants so when you read a line you can find that specific constant. If it is like JSON then you need to create a bunch of regex rules like `if has dashes and then letter end with break line` then it is a block start or something. Somebody suggest a library on the comments.